# Why does createImageBitmap on Android Chrome scale down my images?

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome

I encountered a strange behavior (or unknown feature) of my Chrome 76.0.3809.132 on my Pixel 2 running Android 10. I have a webpage with a file selector and when I select a large JPEG with the size 7151x5363 pixels and pass it to [createImageBitmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/createImageBitmap) then the returned ImageBitmap has the size 1788x1341. So the image is scaled down by factor 4. I even noticed scale factors of 8 for even larger images. Everything works fine with pictures with size 7150x5363 and smaller. PNG images are not affected by it, only JPEGs.

My test page looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="file" type="file" accept="image/*" />
    <script>
    const selector = document.getElementById("file");
    selector.onchange = async () => {
        const file = selector.files[0];
        const image = await createImageBitmap(file);
        alert(`${file.name}: ${image.width}x${image.height}`);
    };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I simply create two JPEGs with sizes 7150x5363 and 7151x5363 in Gimp. Alert output for first image is correct, for second image it is scaled down by factor 4.

So I guess there is some magic hack in Chrome which only reads a smaller version of the JPEG to safe memory. I don't know if this happens only on Android or if it is somehow attached to the amount of available memory. What I'm interested in is some official information about that feature. Maybe a link to the corresponding sources in Chromium (If it is Chromium feature and not a proprietary Android Chrome feature). So far I found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the source code in Chromium. In [image_decoder.cc](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/third_party/blink/renderer/platform/image-decoders/image_decoder.cc#L88) the variable `max_decoded_bytes` is read from the platform and I guess the JPEG decoder uses it (while the PNG decoder doesn't):

```cpp
size_t max_decoded_bytes = Platform::Current()
                                 ? Platform::Current()->MaxDecodedImageBytes()
                                 : kNoDecodedImageByteLimit;
```

The implementation of the `MaxDecodedImageBytes` method is in [blink_platform_impl.cc](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/content/child/blink_platform_impl.cc#L533) and has a special ifdef for Android:

```cpp
#if defined(OS_ANDROID)
  if (base::SysInfo::IsLowEndDevice()) {
    // Limit image decoded size to 3M pixels on low end devices.
    // 4 is maximum number of bytes per pixel.
    return 3 * kMB * kMaxNumberOfBytesPerPixel;
  }
  // For other devices, limit decoded image size based on the amount of physical
  // memory.
  // In some cases all physical memory is not accessible by Chromium, as it can
  // be reserved for direct use by certain hardware. Thus, we set the limit so
  // that 1.6GB of reported physical memory on a 2GB device is enough to set the
  // limit at 16M pixels, which is a desirable value since 4K*4K is a relatively
  // common texture size.
  return base::SysInfo::AmountOfPhysicalMemory() / 25;
#else
```

My device is not a low-end-device so `AmountOfPhysicalMemory()` is important here. This is implemented in [sys_info_linux.cc](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/master/base/system/sys_info_linux.cc#L34):

```cpp
int64_t AmountOfMemory(int pages_name) {
  long pages = sysconf(pages_name);
  long page_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
  if (pages == -1 || page_size == -1) {
    NOTREACHED();
    return 0;
  }
  return static_cast<int64_t>(pages) * page_size;
}

int64_t AmountOfPhysicalMemory() {
  return AmountOfMemory(_SC_PHYS_PAGES);
}
```

So this code retrieves the memory from sysconf. My device has 4 GB RAM and sysconf reports 3834560512 bytes of physical memory. Chromium divides this with 25 so the maximum decoded image size is 153382420 bytes. An image with size 7150x5363 needs 153381800 bytes (width*height*4) so it fits. Image with 7151x5363 needs 153403252 bytes so it doesn't fit so the JPEG decoder reads a smaller version from the JPEG (Which is possible because of the numerator/denominator stuff of JPEGs).

So mystery is solved, there is indeed a special decoded image size limit for Android in Chrome and its basically the RAM size divided by 25.